# how to avoid "CALL16 reloc not against global symbol" for function defined in assembly with gcc on mips

Tags: gcc, linker, mips, elf

This code:

```
__asm__
(
  "f_asm:\n"
  "jr $ra\n"
  "nop\n"
);

void f(void) __asm__("f_asm");

int main(void)
{
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

Yields this error when compiled with `mips-linux-gnu-gcc` on `Debian x64` host:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/mips-linux-gnu/6/../../../../mips-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjejLxv.o: CALL16 reloc at 0x2c not against global symbol
/tmp/ccjejLxv.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It works if I add `.globl f_asm` ... but why is this necessary? Can't one have local functions on `mips` ABIs?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/523991. In fact it's a duplicate. Change `f` prototype to be `static` and all should be well.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Changing the prototype to "static" results in a "used but never defined" warning. I guess I'll re-ask what to do about the warning specifically (I like to compile with -Werror).

Comment: static function and non-static function calls are different in assembly. static uses "jal    my_fn" and non-static call uses "call16(my_fn) + .reloc R_MIPS_JALR + jalr".

Comment: If the function declaration (protptype) is non-static in C then gcc will generate assembly call code as global - using call16(my_fn). Because the function body is inline assembly you need to explicitly mark the function as ".globl my_fn" in the in-line assembly. If you want to use simple static "jal    my_fn" call code then you need to tell this to gcc by marking function declaration (prototype) as static.

Comment: About "used but never defined warning" - It can be ignored. gcc assembly generator (.s file generator) does not really know that __asm__ block is the body of your function. It just inserts the asm block text into final .s program file. Only after that .s file is analyzed by object compiler.